# Deleting an XML DOM node deletes all its siblings

Tags: ms-access, vba, nodes, xmldom

I have to prune an XML document by deleting some nodes. To do that, I have the following VBA function that is called with

- lists = XMLOutput.documentelement
- tagfound = complete path (//Header/Element/Sub-Element/...)

Here is the code:

```
Function RemoveNode(lists, tagfound)
    Dim nodefound As Object
    Set nodefound = lists.selectSingleNode(tagfound)
    If nodefound Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    nodeToBeRemoved = nodefound.basename
    Set x = nodefound.parentnode
    For Each listnode In x.childnodes
        If listnode.basename = nodeToBeRemoved Then
            x.removechild (listnode)
        End If
    Next listnode
End Function
```

I have tried other solutions, more elegant, like a single line of code, but ALL lead to the same result: If I have to remove a child which is the last child of its parent, all its siblings are removed as well. I tried to save the document after any removal, with no results.
Any hints?
To make it more clear, what follows is my input. For each XML tag, a boolean tells me if I have to keep it or to remove it from the XML tree.

XMLTag   ToBeCoded
   Header   TRUE
   Header/Organisation  TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/VAT TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/VAT/Country TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/VAT/Code    TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/SocialSecurity  FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/PersonalData    TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/PersonalData/OrganisationName   TRUE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/PersonalData/PersonalName   FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/PersonalData/FamilyName FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/PersonalData/Title  FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/PersonalData/Code   FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/ProfessionalLedger  FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/ContyOfLedger   FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/EnrollmentNumber    FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/Date    FALSE
   Header/Organisation/BaseData/IRSType FALSE
   Header/Organisation/Location TRUE
   Header/Organisation/Location/Address TRUE
   Header/Organisation/Location/StreetNumber    TRUE
   Header/Organisation/Location/ZIP TRUE
   Header/Organisation/Location/City    TRUE
   Header/Organisation/Location/County  TRUE
   Header/Organisation/Location/Country TRUE

..and this is what I get:

```
<Header>
<Organisation>
   <BaseData>
   <VAT></VAT>
     <PersonalData>
     </PersonalData>
  </BaseData>
  <Location>
    <Address>any street name</Address>
    <StreetNumber>any street number</StreetNumber>
    <ZIP>any ZIP code</ZIP>
    <City>any City</City>
    <County>any County</County>
    <Country>any Country</Country>
   </Location>
```

It is easy to see that I do not get any fields for the tag PersonalData, while I should have removed all children except OrganisationName, which happens to be the first child. Also, BaseData/VAT/Country and BaseData/VAT/Code are not there (the VAT parent is there, but empty).

Comment: why are you looping?   `nodefound.parentnode.removechild nodefound` is sufficient.

Comment: As I said, I tried several different ways. My first code was exactly what you suggested. Same results. I put on a loop hoping that changing names (x instead of nodefound.parentnode, for example) would solve my problem by magic...

Comment: Any XML to go with the above along with expected result?

Comment: `x` is the parent.  `listnode` loops through each `x.childnodes` (therefore listnode is each child, one at a time).  Since `x` is the parent, when you say `x.removechild` you are remove all of the parent's children (aka: siblings).  You need to remove `listnode`, not `x`.  Also, I'd suggest you declare all of your variables (better yet, use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to force proper declaration and handling.)

Comment: Thank a lot for your kind suggestions. However, there is something I do not understand (apologies for my dumbness): as I cannot remove a node directly, but only as a child, I have to use x.removechild by addressing the proper child to be removed. And I assumed that, being x the parent, and list node the child to be removed,  x.removechild(listnode) would do the job. Where am I wrong? And, as far as declaration of variables is concerned, what I posted is an edited excerpt of the actual (long) code, where declarations are properly done, I promise.

Comment: I have added the source file that tells me which tags to keep and which to delete, and the result XML file, where not all what had to be kept is there.

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates the removal of the Zip node

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRemoveNode()

    Dim dom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set dom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    dom.LoadXML "<Header><Organisation><BaseData><VAT></VAT><PersonalData></PersonalData></BaseData><Location>" & _
    "<Address>any street name</Address><StreetNumber>any street number</StreetNumber><ZIP>any ZIP code</ZIP>" & _
    "<City>any City</City><County>any County</County><Country>any Country</Country></Location></Organisation></Header>"
    Debug.Assert dom.parseError = 0

    '* find a node
    Dim xmlZip As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set xmlZip = dom.SelectSingleNode("//ZIP")

    xmlZip.ParentNode.RemoveChild xmlZip

    Debug.Assert dom.XML = "<Header><Organisation><BaseData><VAT></VAT><PersonalData></PersonalData></BaseData><Location>" & _
    "<Address>any street name</Address><StreetNumber>any street number</StreetNumber>" & _
    "<City>any City</City><County>any County</County><Country>any Country</Country></Location></Organisation></Header>" & vbNewLine

End Sub
```